# IE behaving completely different for Iframes

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` which is the target area to display a completely different website inside my website. In Mozilla and chrome I can see the desired output but in Internet explorer sidebar `div` is completely located in a different manner.
Here goes the html code

```html
<div class="menu_sample top_mar">
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">Dashboards</span></li>     
  {% for Dashboard in dashboards %}
<li><a href="{{ Dashboard.d_url }}">{{ Dashboard.d_name }}</a></li>
           {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          
        </div>


    </div>

    
      
      <button class="pushed content" onclick="toggleMenu()" style="margin-top:28%;height:4%;"><span id="menu-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" id="glymphi" style="margin-left:24%;"></span></span></button>




<div style="margin-left:-1%; margin-top:2.5%; height: 625px;" >
<iframe width="100%"  height="100%" name="iframe_a" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

and css is

```css
/* Styles go here */

.menu_sample {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1s ease-out;
  margin-left: -1.5%;
  margin-top: 150%;
}

/*transition*/
.top_mar {
    margin-top: 25%;
}

/* on toggle*/
.content.pushed {
  left: 225px;
}

.hide {
  transform:translateX( -100px);
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this compatibility problem.
in IE---
[image]

in chrome---
[image]

Comment: please define "in IE sidebar div is completely located in a different manner", or provide a screenshot; if it's horizontal scroll you need to get rid of, try: scrolling="yes" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="yes"

Comment: @Manube can you see my updated question with screens shot

Comment: yes, thanks. I may be mistaken, but it looks to me the culprit is your button: glyphicon-chevron-left, not the iframe; try giving your button a width: style="margin-top:28%;height:4%;width:20px" and see what you get...

Comment: you are welcome. I think one of us should post the solution to this issue, so you can tick it as "answered"

Comment: @Manube sure. i have one more doubt?? i.e scroll bars are overlapping only on IE and again in other browsers its fine

Comment: yes, it would seem IE handles things a little differently; try this:-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;

Comment: like this style="scrollbar;"

Comment: or in a css style sheet: html {
-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but it looks to me the culprit is the chevron button `glyphicon-chevron-left`,
and not the iframe;

try giving your button a width, e.g.:

`style="margin-top:28%;height:4%;width:20px"`

otherwise IE will give it maximum width, which is not what you want.

---

Now to prevent IE scrollbar from overlapping your content:

```
html { -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar; }
```